# sub query not working

Tags: sql, ms-access

for some reason my running count column is returning 460 everywhere which is the sum of population values for the first postcode in my table (out of 4 different ones).

Could somebody tell me what's wrong with my code? Thanks:

```
SELECT
target_postcodes.target_postcode as carehome,
population_postcodes.population_postcode as postcodes,
population_postcodes.population as over85,
SQR( (Population_postcodes.Longitude - target_postcodes.longitude)^2 + (Population_postcodes.Latitude - target_postcodes.latitude)^2 ) as distance,
(SELECT sum (population_postcodes.population) as runningcount from population_postcodes) AS runningcount

INTO
cooltable2

FROM
Population_postcodes, Target_postcodes

GROUP BY
target_postcodes.target_postcode,
population_postcodes.population_postcode,
population_postcodes.population,
SQR( (Population_postcodes.Longitude - target_postcodes.longitude)^2 + (Population_postcodes.Latitude - target_postcodes.latitude)^2 )

ORDER BY
SQR( (Population_postcodes.Longitude - target_postcodes.longitude)^2 + (Population_postcodes.Latitude - target_postcodes.latitude)^2 );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a join condition, indicating which rows of one table belong with which rows of the other.

Comment: I cant post a screenshot of the tables as I have too few reputation yet, would you mind upping my question so I can post them?

Comment: Yes, I would very much mind doing that.  As I said, you need to add a join condition, before you go any further.

Answer (score 0):

Two items:

1) The sum() function is applied on a subquery on population_postcodes table which invalidates all your group by conditions.

2) There is no clause that joins the two tables Population_postcodes, Target_postcodes

The query probably should be some thing like....

```
   SELECT
      b.target_postcode as carehome,
      a.population_postcode as postcodes,
      a.population as over85,
      SQR( (a.Longitude - b.longitude)^2 + (a.Latitude - b.latitude)^2 ) as distance,
      sum (a.population) as runningcount
   INTO
      cooltable2
   FROM
      Population_postcodes a, Target_postcodes b
   GROUP BY
      b.target_postcode,
      a.population_postcode,
      a.population,
      SQR( (a.Longitude - b.longitude)^2 + (a.Latitude - b.latitude)^2 )
   ORDER BY
      SQR( (a.Longitude - b.longitude)^2 + (a.Latitude - b.latitude)^2 )
```

Comment: The problem with joining tables is that i have no column to join them on, so this would yield an empty table.

Comment: Try, the above without the inner join clause.

Comment: I did, and it only returns tje value in the population column